# C# change settings file name

Tags: c#, properties, settings

In C#, is it possible to change the "Default" name for the settings file without having to create an additional settings file? For example, instead of using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1
```

I want to use:

`Properties.Settings.Group1.Setting1` and `Properties.Settings.Group2.Setting2`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `Settings` is a partial class. You can write a `partial class Settings` with your own properties. In my opinion, this is exactly why it is a partial class.

I wouldn't recommend changing the *default* `Default` property. You can, however write the following:

```
public partial class Settings {

   // provide custom Groups, etc.
   public void Group1 {
      // some specific collection or object
      return Group1.Settings
   }

   public void Group2 {
      // some specific collection or object
      return Group2.Settings
   }
}
```

...where `Group1` and `Group2` represent custom classes. Each `Group` object can have their own methods for saving data, settings, configurations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you update your setting, add this code to persist

```
Properties.Settings.OtherName.Setting1 = ...;
Properties.Settings.OtherName.Save();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't what @Luis is asking, although I can't quite figure out the exact meaning of the question

Comment: Change settings file name : the title of post, @Luis can arbitrate, After I do my best

Comment: No matter what the filename is, if you name it MySettings then you would have to use Properties.MySettings.Default.Setting1. What I want is to use Properties.Mysettings.OtherName.Setting1